# iPhone app--newbie authentication question

Tags: iphone

I have a web app that has standard user model information. I am building an iPhone app to communicate with the endpoints in my current web app to authenticate the user and all the actions he/she can do. What is the standard approach for this? OAuth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a UIWebView or use ASIHTTPRequest.

Answer (score 0):

Create a webservice on top of the web app.. MAke iphone app comunicate through that webservice by parsing the data... And the easiest way to parse is by using this library.. http://sudzc.com/